# TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present and must be an object

Tags: webassembly

I'm following this "hello world" tutorial:
https://steemit.com/eos/@skenan/eos-development-for-beginners-webassembly

and I get this error:

> TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present and must be an object

Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: A link to the tutorial is helpful, but a code block with your code would be the most helpful. It's hard to say what's wrong when we have no idea what you have for code.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you got this error is probably because:
when you initiate a webassembly instance, you need to specify the import object as well. Just like:

```
WebAssembly.instantiate(module, imports);
```

Well, here I'm just giving a simple example to demonstrate the steps:

```
    imports.env = imports.env || {}

    Object.assign(imports.env, {
      tableBase: module.tableBase,
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 4,
        element: 'anyfunc',
      }),
      print:function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
      }
    });
    return new WebAssembly.Instance(module, imports)
```

Comment: Where did the "imports" object come from?

Comment: I don't even know what `imports` does...

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to reproduce this error by following the tutorial. It works fine for me. Did you make any changes to the C source or JavaScript loading code?

The error you are seeing occurs if you instantiate a module without giving it all its required imports. But a module without imports like the one in the tutorial can be instantiated without an imports object. Documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiate#Parameters.